# Program ICON not in Applications List

Tags: software-installation

I installed gtp4all and got the following error in the logs:

```
[2365695] Operation \"CreateDesktopEntry\" with arguments \"/home/benjamin/Desktop/GPT4All.desktop; Type=Application\nTerminal=false\nExec=\"/home/benjamin/gpt4all/bin/chat\"\nName=GPT4All\nIcon=/home/benjamin/gpt4all/logo-48.png\nName[en_US]=GPT4All\" failed: Konnte keinen Eintrag \"/home/benjamin/Desktop/GPT4All.desktop\" auf dem Arbeitsplatz anlegen.
[2365695] installationErrorWithCancel : Installationsfehler : Fehler beim Installieren von Komponente gpt4all:
Konnte keinen Eintrag "/home/benjamin/Desktop/GPT4All.desktop" auf dem Arbeitsplatz anlegen. Retry|Ignore|Cancel
```

Can I do this CreateDesktopEntry somehow manually, what would be the way to do it? Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. All information is in the first error message.

The application attempted to create a `.desktop` launcher in the directory`/home/benjamin/Desktop/GPT4All.desktop`: this is a launcher on your desktop.

The contents of that file are also indicated. To make this a valid `.desktop` file, one line need to be added on the first line, so the content becomes:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec="/home/benjamin/gpt4all/bin/chat"
Name=GPT4All
Icon=/home/benjamin/gpt4all/logo-48.png
Name[en_US]=GPT4All
```

So, with a text editor, create the file and paste the contents in it.